# Why JSON conversion returns Array?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I don t  know why data formated as json using **JSON.parse  function** return as **Array type** when I want to check the new converted type.

First I made ajax request to go and fetch data from a database as illustrated below

```
$.ajax({
   url:'processBet.php',
   data:'',
   success:function(data){  
    //below I check the return data type
      console.log( Object.getPrototypeOf(JSON.parse(data)));
    //the return type is array.....why?
     console.log((JSON.parse(data)); // to see the data

   }
});
```

Obviously in the file that fetch data in the **database** will put data  in Array.So before sending it I converted it in JSON using **a php function json_encode**  as illustrated below

```
$ql = "SELECT * from   tempdata" ;
    $result=$pdo->query($ql);
    $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while($data = $result->fetch()){
        $arrays[]=$data;
    }
//Now I convert in json before sending
 $json =json_encode($arrays);
 echo $json;  // the return data supposed to be json type
```

**Below is the sample of the data return after succeessfull ajax request**
[image]

**So Iwould like to know why the return type is still array and not JSON since a new conversion has been made when the ajax request succeed**

Comment: Because you put it through `JSON.parse`, which turned it back into the array that it was before you `json_encode`'d it. You should try `console.log( Object.getPrototypeOf(data));` which will give you `String` instead.

Comment: Yes I did this to get the type of the return data .My question is that :is it correct because I must be sure of that  so that no bugs can come along.Thanks

Comment: Array is not a type, nor is JSON. *Object.getPrototypeOf* effectively returns the name of the constructor for the first prototype found on the `[[Prototype]]` chain.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because how you are setting up your array before encoding it.

`$arrays[] = $data;`

PHP will set it as an object if the depth of the elements go beyond just an array of arrays.

---

### Example:

If you create a simple 2d array like this one:

```
$p = [
    'name' => 'jack',
    'job' => 'ceo',
    'age' => 'old'
]; // {"name":"jack","job":"ceo","age":"old"}
```

You will have an Object in your JS code; That's because of the way PHP handles it. However, look at this example as an alternative: This will return an array of objects:

```
$p = [[
    'name' => 'jack',
    'job' => 'ceo',
    'age' => 'old'
],[
    'name' => 'sam',
    'job' => 'cool',
    'age' => 'decent'
]];

echo json_encode($p); //[{"name":"jack","job":"ceo","age":"old"},{"name":"sam","job":"cool","age":"decent"}]
```

It's all about that key placement. If you have a `key => pair` array it will become an Object no matter what. Look at another example of a simple JS array:

```
print_r(json_encode([
    'burger',
    'pizza'
])); // ["burger","pizza"]
```

But if you add just one `key=>pair` to your array it will become an json object:

```
print_r(json_encode([
    'burger',
    'pizza',
    'people' => [
        'jack' ,
        'sam',
        'pete'
    ]
])); // {"0":"burger","1":"pizza","people":["jack","sam","pete"]}
```

Just for educational purpose if you throw it inside another 1d array you will get an array objects:

```
print_r(json_encode([[
    'burger',
    'pizza',
    'people' => [
        'jack' ,
        'sam',
        'pete'
    ]
]])); // [{"0":"burger","1":"pizza","people":["jack","sam","pete"]}]
```

---

### Explanation:

When dealing with an array, it will strictly handle it's key from `0` to however many items are in the array; so an `array` in `json_encode` terms is anything with a simple 1d interface:

Which in PHP & JavaScript would look like this:

PHP

```
print_r([
  'burger',
  'pizza'
]); // Array ( [0] => burger [1] => pizza )
```

Javascript

```
console.log([
  'burger',
  'pizza'
]); // Array [ "burger", "pizza" ]
```

When adding the `key` to your array and making it into a 2d or more complex `json_encode` will convert it to a JavaScript Object; as we saw in the first example:

Comment: Thanks for this explanation From today I know that the key of the Array play a big role in the conversion process

Comment: @GNETODOMINIQUE yeah man; other than that `json_encode` docs are not great at explaining the difference. That's just an observation I made during my time writing PHP

Comment: Dont worry I know that this may not be the official explanation but it helps a lot.You did a good conclusion